# Does chrome debug tools "port forwarding" work on native apps as well as webview apps?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm using [Chrome port forwarding](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#port-forwarding) on my Cordova-based hybrid app, and it works fine for AJAX calls made from HTML/Javascript. As expected, AJAX calls to http://localhost:8080 forward to my desktop where my development server is running Apache on port 80. See image below.

However, my app also makes an HTTP request in native code (I'm registering for GCM messages). As far as I can tell, the port forwarding does not work for that request.

I'm using standard Java (no special HTTP client classes or anything):

```
URLConnection yc = registration_url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
etc.
```

Does anyone know how Chrome port forwarding works? Is it a proxy at the OS level of the device, or somehow built into WebView? Has anyone been able to get this to work with native code?

FYI: I could convert my GCM registration to Javascript, but am hoping to avoid that work.

[image]

Comment: If you aren't familiar with port forwarding see: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#port-forwarding

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Chrome port forwarding only works within WebView. For native code, I ran adb port forwarding and that worked.

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:80
```

So on an app which uses both Javascript network calls and native network calls, I need to run both tools.

Any comments on how this works would be very helpful.